# How to access multiple image URL from one app to another app in django

Tags: django

I have two apps in my project.

**They are:**

> Blog app
>
> Accounts app

In `accounts` app contains user profiles like Images, Bio, DOB etc, In blog app each user has their own `blog` page and Each page must have `comments` so any user can comment any `blog`. In comments section, it shows `username` and his unique profile `URL`.**Now my problem is** I can't load their profile images. 
**models.py**

```
class comments(models.Model):
     blogger= models.ForeignKey(blog,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     comment = models.TextField()
     def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse('blog:comments',args = [ self.id])
```

**views.py**

```
commentz = comments.objects.filter(blogger= id).all().order_by('-created')[:10]
for pic in commentz:
    image = UserProfile.objects.filter(user = pic.user)
```

I know this is insane **:-/**

Comment: How are you serving the images?

Comment: images are stored in accounts app--->models.py--> image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

Comment: I want to display users images who are commented in a blog page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved.when we render an image from one app to another.we need to use absolute URL and inside hyperlink, we have to call models name.In my case model name is `UserProfile`.

`<a href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile' username=c.user %}"><img src="{{ 
  c.user.userprofile.image.url }}"></a>`

```
{% if class_comments %}
    {% for c in class_comments %}
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile' username=c.user %}"><img class="img-responsive user-photo" src="{{ c.user.userprofile.image.url }}"></a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`annotate` can help to look up `relational` fields

```
from django.db.models import F

# include image field in queryset
commentz = comments.objects.annotate(image=F('user__image')).filter(blogger= id).all().order_by('-created')[:10]

# Access image
commentz[0].image
```